# Cordova Android JDK Requirement

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

On the cordova website, it says the requirement is 1.7 or greater.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/

I recently updated `ionic`, `cordova`, and `cordova-android` platform:

```
cordova: 6.5.0
android: 6.1.2
ionic: 2.2.1
```

Now when I run `ionic run android --device`:

I get:

`Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater`

**Do I have to upgrade the JDK or is there another method?**

I have another java project needs to stay on JDK 1.7

Answer (score 0):

You gotta get JDK 1.8 to make it working. You can install JDK 1.8 and set the path of JDK 1.8 in the system environment `path` variable to make use of JDK 1.8

JDK 1.7 can still remain as is and you can switch the path to JDK 1.7 when your other JAVA project demands it. Hope it helps. Cheers.